# MYSQL & PHP Display data from multiple tables

Tags: php, sql

I have a database that has three tables with the same fields. I'm trying to get it to display the content, but I'm running into two issues. Here is what is on the PHP file. Can someone please help?

Issue 1: Only one table displays
Issue 2: If I add all tables and any have no data the out put is `NULL`

(I tried adding `$query = "SELECT * FROM main_office,second_office,third_office";` but that didn't work.)

```
<?php
    class Location {
        public $address;
        public $city;
        public $us_state;
        public $zip;
        public $longitude;
        public $latitude;

    public function setAddress($address) {
        $this->address = $address;
    }
    public function setCity($city) {
        $this->city = $city;
    }
    public function setState($us_state) {
        $this->us_state = $us_state;
    }
    public function setZip($zip) {
        $this->zip = $zip;
    }
    public function setLongitude($longitude) {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }
    public function setLatitude($latitude) {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }
    }

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

require 'config.php';

    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM main_office";
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $location[$j] = new Location;
    $location[$j]->setAddress($row[5]);
    $location[$j]->setCity($row[6]);
    $location[$j]->setState($row[7]);
    $location[$j]->setZip($row[8]);
    $location[$j]->setLongitude($row[9]);
    $location[$j]->setLatitude($row[10]);
}

$json_string = json_encode($location); 
echo $json_string; 

?>
```

Comment: Do not, I repeat, DO NOT, use the mysql_* interface. Switch to mysqli or PDO.  It is deprecated and gone in the latest PHP release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `union all` operation:

```
SELECT *
FROM main_office
union all
select *
from second_office
union all
select *
from third_office;
```

This appends all the rows together.  Your original version was doing a Cartesian product of the tables.  That is, the output consisted of all combinations of all rows from all three tables.  So, the total rows output would be the product of the rows in the three tables.  And, no rows in one table means that no rows are output.